# How to install custom version of the plyr package

Tags: r

I modified the plyr package and built it in R and and it resides on my local computer at

...Documents\R-3.1.2\library\plyr

Now I have another "computer B" that I want to use this modified version of plyr

How do I get this modified version of plyr on computer B?

I see a plyr.dll in the libs\x64 folder on my computer

...Documents\R-3.1.2\library\plyr\libs\x64

Do I just delete the current plyr package on computer B and place the the plyr.dll from my computer on computer B?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do.

1. Fork the plyr package on Github
2. Apply your changes to your fork
3. Use `devtools::_install_github()` to install the package on the machines

If the changes are interesting: submit a pull request to the original repository so that other can benefit from it.

Comment: HI Thierry unfortunatley I cannot use Github.  Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: You can use Bitbucket with `devtools::install_bitbucket()` or even a local git repository with `devtools::install_git()`